# Generate Server Side Images for different Devices?

Tags: java, android, ios, objective-c, swift

Case: I have an app for Android, Android Tablet, iPhone, iPad. Server has a backend to upload image (not the app). App user can browse these server side uploaded images on their phones.

The images which are uploaded from a server backend can be of square and rectangle dimension.

Note that I support all iOS devices and all Android devices. The simples way of doing it is serving one big image for all the devices.

Qustions:

- What display size should be reference for the image dimension being uploaded?
- Which sizes should be created on the server from the uploaded image?

Comment: You place the original images on the server. Your apps request images with a width and height parameter. Let your server resize the images on the fly.

Comment: What kind of server is this? You could give some more info.

Comment: It is an Grails based server which provides a REST interface to the app.

Comment: If you had read the answers and comments here you should have known that you you should name the protocoll too. Is it http?

Answer (score 0):

you have to upload high dimension images only.In server side there is a magic view funtionality you have to implement.In App side when you got image url from server side then check your device resolution type and then set resolution size for that image in application.

Comment: You mean just store one big image and use it for all phone screens?

Comment: yes,you can find the device type or resolution of screen and when you get the image from server the same image can be set with different resolutions..

Answer (score 0):

You could resize the images at the time of request depending on what is most important, the speed of the request or the memory footprint.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745147/java-resize-image-without-losing-quality) post gives a clear example on how to resize images.

Comment: Agreed that resizing should be done at request time on server. But i do not see how the code you proposed could help with that. How would it be invoked? If the server uses php for instance.

Comment: I assumed that a java server was used and in this case you could have sent the images (scaled with the provided code) via soap messages for example.