# JButton image pixelated

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I'm currently working on a personal use application in Java. I have started the design phase and I have a problem with adding an icon for my button. The image is always pixelated and I don't understand why.

Here is the code of the panel where the button is located:

```
BufferedImage lockIcon = ImageIO.read(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\resources\\icon_lock.png"));

this.setSize(1280, 100);
GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{100, 717, 0};
gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{100, 0};
gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
setLayout(gridBagLayout);

this.setBackground(new Color(142, 59, 70));

JButton lockingButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon(lockIcon));
lockingButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
lockingButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);

GridBagConstraints gbc_lockButton = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc_lockButton.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc_lockButton.insets = new Insets(10, 5, 0, 5);
gbc_lockButton.gridx = 0;
gbc_lockButton.gridy = 0;
add(lockingButton, gbc_lockButton);
```

My icon is a .png with a size of 100x100 pixels and a resolution of 300 dpi and the size of my frame is 1280x720 pixels. I've already tried to change the image size and I also to modify the layout of my panel but it didn't change anything.

Here is a screenshot of the result:

[image]

So my question is: How can I solve this problem, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Scaling a low-resolution image to a higher resolution display area is going to result in scaling artifacts.  The more you scale, the more exaggerated the artifacting.  You might consider a vector drawable library and represent your image as a vector drawable.

Comment: Will lppk into this more tomorrow, but 2 things I can tell you right now: 1. As Michael Krause said, using a library (like Ikonli) will give you better resolution and save time. 2. You can manually scale the image to the button size before using it or, if you don‘t know the size, do it programatically (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745147/java-resize-image-without-losing-quality)

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and to be honest I'm a bit confused...
JButton itself does not scale the image to fill, it just gets centered, so I don't see a reason for it to loose quality (tested it with my own icon and it looked fine).

In general I do not recommend scaling icons with the rest of the UI (dynamic size determined by the `LayoutManager`), so you should be able to scale the image before adding it to the button using following line:

```
image = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
```

If you still wish to scale the image with the UI you override the buttons `getIcon()` method and do the scaling there.

As stated in my comment, if you want to do really high end scaling you could try the options provided here: [Java - resize image without losing quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745147/java-resize-image-without-losing-quality)


**BONUS:**
I'm not sure why it would pixelate in your case, but I can give you something that may help:
I created a Component specifically for Images and specialized on being used as buttons.
It will scale the image with the smooth option. It will also abide if the layout forces a size or you set one manually and scale the image (keeping the aspect ratio) instead of centering.

If no size is set, it will default to text height.

You may also call `jImage.generateStateImages();` to let it automatically create clicked, hovered and disabled images (by altering brightness and gray-scaling).

As soon as you add an action listener it will start behaving (but not looking) like a `JButton`.

```
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;
import java.awt.image.ImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.ImageProducer;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.GrayFilter;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class JImage extends JLabel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image image;
    private Image disabledImage;
    private Image hoveredImage;
    private Image clickedImage;
    private final Map<Image, Image> scaledInstances = new HashMap<Image, Image>();

    private boolean enabled = true;
    private boolean hovered;
    private boolean clicked;

    private final List<ActionListener> actionListeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();

    private boolean isCursorSet = false;
    private boolean mouseListenersInitialized = false;


    public JImage(Icon icon){
        this(toImage(icon));
    }

    public JImage(Image image){
        this.image = image;
        addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

            @Override
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
                    if(!actionListeners.isEmpty()){
                        doClick();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initMouseListeners(){
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
                clicked = false;
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                clicked = true;
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                hovered = false;
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                hovered = true;
                repaint();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                doClick(e.getButton());
            }
        });

        mouseListenersInitialized = true;
    }

    public void doClick(){
        doClick(MouseEvent.BUTTON1);
    }

    public void doClick(int mouseButton){
        if(isEnabled() && mouseButton == MouseEvent.BUTTON1){
            for(ActionListener actionListener : getActionListeners()) actionListener.actionPerformed(new ActionEvent(this, ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED, "mouseClicked"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        if(super.isPreferredSizeSet()){
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }else if(getImage() != null){
            int height = getFontMetrics(getFont()).getHeight();
            double imageRatio = (double) getImage().getWidth(null) / getImage().getHeight(null);
            int width = (int) (height * imageRatio);
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }else return new Dimension(0, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getMinimumSize(){
        return getPreferredSize();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.setCursor(getCursor());
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Image image;
        if(!isEnabled() && getDisabledImage() != null) image = getDisabledImage();
        else if(clicked && getClickedImage() != null) image = getClickedImage();
        else if((hovered || isFocusOwner()) && getHoveredImage() != null) image = getHoveredImage();
        else image = this.getImage();

        if(image != null){
            if(image.getWidth(null) == 0 || image.getHeight(null) == 0) System.out.println("not yet loaded");
            Insets insets;
            if(getBorder() == null){
                insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }else{
                insets = getBorder().getBorderInsets(this);
            }
            int width = getWidth() - insets.right - insets.left;
            int height = getHeight() - insets.bottom - insets.top;
            double imageRatio = (double) image.getWidth(null) / image.getHeight(null);
            double containerRatio = (double) width / height;
            if(imageRatio > containerRatio){
                height = (int) (width / imageRatio);
            }else{
                width = (int) (height * imageRatio);
            }
            int x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;

            Image scaled = scaledInstances.get(image);
            if(scaled == null || scaled.getWidth(null) != width || scaled.getHeight(null) != height){
                scaled = image.getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                scaledInstances.put(image, scaled);
            }

            g.drawImage(scaled, x, y, null);
        }
    }

    public void scalePreferredSize(float scale){
        Dimension prefSize = getPreferredSize();
        prefSize.width *= scale;
        prefSize.height *= scale;
        setPreferredSize(prefSize);
    }

    /**
     * Convenience method to use JImages as Buttons
     * <br/>Adds a click listener.
     * <br/>Also changes the cursor to a hand cursor when on top of this component.
     * <br/>To revert this, call {@link #setCursor(java.awt.Cursor)}
     * @param actionListener the listener to be called on click
     */
    public void addActionListener(final ActionListener actionListener) {
        actionListeners.add(actionListener);
        if(!mouseListenersInitialized) initMouseListeners();
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    protected List<ActionListener> getActionListeners(){
        return actionListeners;
    }

    public void generateStateImages(){
        generateStateImages(true, true, true);
    }

    public void generateStateImages(boolean disabled, boolean hovered, boolean clicked){
        if(image == null) throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot generate state images while default image is null.");
        if(disabled){
            this.disabledImage = grayScale(image);
        }
        if(hovered){
            this.hoveredImage = changeBrightness(image, 1.2f);
        }
        if(clicked){
            this.clickedImage = changeBrightness(image, 0.8f);
        }
        if(!mouseListenersInitialized) initMouseListeners();
    }

    public Image getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(Image image) {
        this.image = image;
        repaint();
    }

    public Image getDisabledImage() {
        return disabledImage;
    }

    public void setDisabledImage(Image disabledImage) {
        this.disabledImage = disabledImage;
        if(!mouseListenersInitialized && disabledImage != null) initMouseListeners();
        repaint();
    }

    public Image getHoveredImage() {
        return hoveredImage;
    }

    public void setHoveredImage(Image hoveredImage) {
        this.hoveredImage = hoveredImage;
        if(!mouseListenersInitialized && hoveredImage != null) initMouseListeners();
        repaint();
    }

    public Image getClickedImage() {
        return clickedImage;
    }

    public void setClickedImage(Image clickedImage) {
        this.clickedImage = clickedImage;
        if(!mouseListenersInitialized && clickedImage != null) initMouseListeners();
        repaint();
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
        repaint();
    }

    public boolean isHovered() {
        return hovered;
    }

    public boolean isClicked() {
        return clicked;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor getCursor(){
        if(!isCursorSet && !actionListeners.isEmpty() && isEnabled()) return Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(isEnabled() ? Cursor.HAND_CURSOR : Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
        else return super.getCursor();
    }

    @Override
    public void setCursor(Cursor cursor){
        super.setCursor(cursor);
        isCursorSet = true;
    }

    /**
     * @return a copy that will update its image when the original its updated.
     */
    public JImage createDelegate(){
        final JImage thisImage = this;
        JImage delegate = new JImage(getImage()){

            public boolean isEnabled() {
                return thisImage.isEnabled();
            }

            public List<ActionListener> getActionListeners(){
                List<ActionListener> actionListeners = new ArrayList<ActionListener>(thisImage.getActionListeners());
                actionListeners.addAll(super.getActionListeners());
                return actionListeners;
            }

            public Image getImage() {
                return thisImage.getImage();
            }

            public Image getDisabledImage() {
                return thisImage.getDisabledImage();
            }

            public Image getHoveredImage() {
                return thisImage.getHoveredImage();
            }

            public Image getClickedImage() {
                return thisImage.getClickedImage();
            }
        };

        return delegate;
    }

    // Extracted from my image utilities
    private static Image grayScale(Image image){
        ImageFilter filter = new GrayFilter(true, 50);  
        ImageProducer producer = new FilteredImageSource(image.getSource(), filter);  
        return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(producer);  
    }

    // Extracted from my image utilities
    private static Image changeBrightness(Image image, float mult) {
        BufferedImage newImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        newImage.getGraphics().drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

        WritableRaster wr = newImage.getRaster();
        int[] pixel = new int[4];
        int[] overflows = new int[3];

        for(int i = 0; i < wr.getWidth(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < wr.getHeight(); j++){
                wr.getPixel(i, j, pixel);
                pixel[0] = (int) (pixel[0] * mult);
                pixel[1] = (int) (pixel[1] * mult);
                pixel[2] = (int) (pixel[2] * mult);

                // if a value exceeds 255, the other color values will instead be raised to bleach the image
                overflows[0] = 0;
                overflows[1] = 0;
                overflows[2] = 0;
                if(pixel[0] > 255){
                    overflows[1] += pixel[0] - 255;
                    overflows[2] += pixel[0] - 255;
                    pixel[0] = 255;
                }
                if(pixel[1] > 255){
                    pixel[0] += pixel[1] - 255;
                    pixel[2] += pixel[1] - 255;
                    pixel[1] = 255;
                }
                if(pixel[2] > 255){
                    pixel[0] += pixel[2] - 255;
                    pixel[1] += pixel[2] - 255;
                    pixel[2] = 255;
                }
                pixel[0] = Math.min(255, pixel[0] + overflows[0]);
                pixel[1] = Math.min(255, pixel[1] + overflows[1]);
                pixel[2] = Math.min(255, pixel[2] + overflows[2]);

                wr.setPixel(i, j, pixel);
            }
        }

        return newImage;
    }

    // Extracted from my image utilities
    private static Image toImage(Icon icon){
        if (icon instanceof ImageIcon) {
            return ((ImageIcon) icon).getImage();
        } else {
            int w = icon.getIconWidth();
            int h = icon.getIconHeight();
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
            icon.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
            g.dispose();
            return image;
        }
    }


}
```