# Image displayed in original size and cropped instead of scaled down

Tags: java, image, user-interface, image-processing, scaling

I am writing a program that is supposed to display changing images in a slideshow. For that the intent is to scale down the images so they will not burst out of the borders of the screen. But instead of being displayed as scaled down, the images are shown in their original size and cropped at the sides.

By now I have already tried different approaches - trying the methods .getScaledInstance() (which is only delivering this nonsense), tried to redraw the files using Graphis or Graphis2D, which only returned white surfaces, tried implementing Scalr and Thumbnator (which didn't work at all but only threw error messages) and Marvin which wouldn't even compile. So possible solutions like [in this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-resize-image) or [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745147/java-resize-image-without-losing-quality) have been unsuccessfull for me.

At this point I am seriously lost and in dire need of help.

The code I am using is in this state right now:

```
    public class Main {
        
        Dimension screenSize = new Dimension();
        DisplayImage comp = new DisplayImage();
        File error = new File("error.jpg");

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
            List<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
            
            //fill the list
            fileList.add(new File("test1.jpg"));
            fileList.add(new File("test2.jpg"));
            fileList.add(new File("test3.jpg"));
            fileList.add(new File("test4.jpg"));
            
            screenSize.setSize(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getWidth(), GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getHeight());
            JFrame frame = TextDisplay.displayText(comp, screenSize);
            long refactoring = System.currentTimeMillis();
            
            for (int i = 0;i<fileList.size();i++) {
                
                while (1*1000 > System.currentTimeMillis() - refactoring+2) {
                    Thread.sleep(1l);       //SlideShow is supposed to wait for a fixed amount of time before loading the next picture
                }
                loadDisplay(fileList.get(i));
            }
            frame.dispose();
        }

        //loads a new picture into the JComponent, updating the old one.
        private void loadDisplay(File imageFile) throws IOException {
            
            if (imageFile.exists()) {
                if(ImageIO.read(imageFile) != null) {
                    comp.setImage(DisplayImage.displayImage(imageFile, screenSize));
                } else {
                    comp.setImage(DisplayImage.displayImage(error, screenSize));
                }
            } else {
                comp.setImage(DisplayImage.displayImage(error, screenSize));
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    //This extension class for JComponent is supposed to organize the pictures for the slideshow
    public class DisplayImage extends JComponent {
        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 8027213542020243319L;
        private static Image image;
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           if (image != null) {
              g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
           }
        }
        
        //This method that is supposed to load and (if neccessary) rescale the pictures.
        public static Image displayImage(File f, Dimension screenSize) throws IOException {
            
            BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(f);
            double width = screenSize.getWidth()*0.75;
            double z1 = (originalImage.getWidth()/width);
            double z2 = (originalImage.getHeight()/(screenSize.getHeight()-20));
            int setWidth, setHeight;

            //case 1: height is smaller than width so scaling depends on the width
            if (originalImage.getHeight()/z1 <= width && originalImage.getHeight()/z1 < (screenSize.getHeight()-20)) {

                if (originalImage.getWidth()/z1 < width) {
                    setWidth = (int) width;
                    setHeight = (int)((originalImage.getHeight()/z1)*((originalImage.getWidth()/z1)/width));
                } else {
                    setWidth = (int) (originalImage.getWidth()/z1);
                    setHeight = (int)(originalImage.getHeight()/z1);
                }

            //case 2: width is smaller than height so scaling depends on the height
            } else {
                if (originalImage.getHeight()/z2 < (screenSize.getHeight()-20)) {
                    setWidth = (int) width;
                    setHeight = (int)((originalImage.getHeight()/z2)/(originalImage.getWidth()/z2)*width);
                } else {
                    setWidth = (int) (originalImage.getWidth()/z2);
                    setHeight = (int)(originalImage.getHeight()/z2);
                }
            }
            return originalImage.getScaledInstance(setWidth, setHeight, Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING);
        }
    }


    //This class is supposed to organize the frame-elements for the slideshow.
    //The frame should contain a place fot the scaled down picture as well as a text area to display text to the pictures.
    public class TextDisplay {
        
        public static JTextArea textField = new JTextArea();
        private static JSplitPane panelText = new JSplitPane();
        private final static JSplitPane mainPanel = new JSplitPane();
        private static JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        public static void setText(String string) {
            operatorsField.setText(string);     
        }   

        public static void setFont(Font font) {
            operatorsField.setFont(font);       
        }
        
        
        public static JFrame displayText(DisplayImage comp, Dimension screenSize) {
            
            textField.setLayout((LayoutManager) new BoxLayout(textField, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenSize.getWidth()/5,screenSize.getHeight()));
            textField.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 25));
            textField.setLineWrap(true);
            textField.setWrapStyleWord(true);
            textField.setEditable(false);
            textField.setFocusable(true);
            
            
            panelText.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelText, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            panelText.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
            panelText.setOneTouchExpandable(false);
            panelText.setFocusable(true);
            panelText.setBottomComponent(textField);
            
            mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            mainPanel.setOrientation(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
            mainPanel.setDividerLocation(70);
            mainPanel.setDividerSize(0);
            mainPanel.setOneTouchExpandable(false);
            mainPanel.setFocusable(true);
            mainPanel.setBottomComponent(panelText);
            mainPanel.setEnabled(false);
        
            
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setPreferredSize(screenSize);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(comp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.add(mainPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
            frame.pack();
            
            return frame;
        }
    }
```

How do I make the program scale down the images I want to display instead of cropping them?

Comment: Please include the rest of your code - how are you drawing to your screen? Where is `screenSize` coming from? Is your program fullscreen?

Comment: As well as resizing, it seems like what you want to do is *Maintain The Aspect Ratio* of your images when they are scaled to fit your display component so that those images are not distorted when in view.

Comment: @Daniel Centore: I get screenSize from ```screenSize.setSize(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getWidth(), GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getScreenDevices()[0].getDisplayMode().getHeight());```

and yes, the program is supposed to be fullscreen.

Comment: Edited the code now for all that I could find to be neccessary for this project. Hope this helps now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        File pathToFile = new File("./doggo.jpeg");
        Image img = ImageIO.read(pathToFile);
        
        JComponent panel = new JComponent()
        {
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

                int w = this.getWidth();
                int h = this.getHeight();

                int[] scale = scaleImage(img, w, h);

                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2.drawImage(img, scale[2], scale[3], scale[0], scale[1], null);
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setBackground(Color.black);
        
        GraphicsDevice gd =
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();

        if (gd.isFullScreenSupported()) {
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            gd.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Full screen not supported");
            frame.setSize(765, 1024);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static int[] scaleImage(Image image, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
        double thumbRatio = (double) newWidth / (double) newHeight;
        int imageWidth = image.getWidth(null);
        int imageHeight = image.getHeight(null);
        double aspectRatio = (double) imageWidth / (double) imageHeight;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;

        if (thumbRatio < aspectRatio) {
            y = newHeight;
            newHeight = (int) (newWidth / aspectRatio);
            y /= 2;
            y -= newHeight / 2;
        } else {
            x = newWidth;
            newWidth = (int) (newHeight * aspectRatio);
            x /= 2;
            x -= newWidth / 2;
        }

        return new int[] { newWidth, newHeight, x, y };
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly instead of now displaying the image scaled down I get a black layer over the original image in the now scaled down size. But the original is still not scaled at all :(

Comment: @DanielJanz It's hard to debug without you providing more code. I've edited the post to provide a complete, working example that you can reference.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a try again. Also will see if I can add more code without having to display all the program. Already tried it yesterday but got lost in the process and had to roll back to the original code I showed here.
I will keep you informed.

Comment: It can be a good idea to build a separate, minimal project to figure out just this one thing before incorporating the ideas into a more complex project

Comment: Made it work thanks to your solution! I was able to restructure the @Override so it would actually match my code. In retrospect it seems that my spacing-method worked as well but the mistake was how I was using the JComponent. With applying your variation to it it also got finally all the functionality which I intended.
Thank you very, very much for your help. I couldn't have done it without you! :)